# Perl grocery program

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, if-statement, hash

I have an array of grocery items I need to buy and a hash with grocery items as keys and the cost of those items as the values. I need a program that will tell me the total cost of my bill based on what's available in the hash and for it to tell me the items that are not available. How should I go about doing this? This is what I have so far:

```
my %stash = ('tofu' => .30, 'berrys' => .30, 'water' => .30, 'nuts' => .30, 'chips' => .30, 'soda' => .30, 'jam' => .30, 'meat' => .30, 'kale' => .30, 'peas' => .30); 

my @itemsneeded = ('tofu', 'berrys', 'water', 'nuts', 'chips', 'rice', 'vinegar');
```

In pseudocode, I want to loop through my items needed and if it equals the keys in `%stash`, for it to sum the cost of those items and if the item is not available, for those names be stored in another variable. then the total cost and the unavailable items would be printed out. i did this so far:

```
foreach my $items (@itemsneeded) {
if ($items eq
```

and i'm stuck there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. SO isn't suited to teaching programming from scratch, but rather answering specific questions. I'd suggest you start with https://www.perl.org/learn.html, learn some Perl, take a shot at coding this up, and come back with specific questions. If you've already got some code, let's see it!

Comment: @Schwern hi Schwern! thank you for your reply. I just posted what I have so far...any help would be so great :)

Comment: You want to get the values of the items in the hash and add them together. In your loop, you would access the values like so: `$stash{$item}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, start by making things sane.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
```

That turns on [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html), now undeclared variables are an error. It turns on [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) so Perl will warn you when you do things that look like mistakes. And it turns on [5.10 features](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#FEATURE-BUNDLES), the most important of which is [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html).

You've got your data set up right. Next you need places to store your total and unavailable items.

```
my $total = 0;
my @unavailable;
```

Then loop through your `@itemsneeded` checking which ones are available and adding their price to your `$total`.

```
for my $item (@itemsneeded) {
    if( defined $stash{$item} ) {
        $total += $stash{$item};
    }
    else {
        push @unavailable, $item;
    }
}
```

`defined $stash{$item}` checks whether the `$item` is in `%stash` and has a defined value. If it does, add its price to the `$total`.

`push @unavailable, $item;` adds the item to the end of the list of `@unavailable` items.

Then print them. A bit of formatting is required.

```
printf "The total cost is %.2f\n", $total;
```

If you just print out `$total` you'll get something like `0.3` which isn't how we write money. `%.2f` says to write the number with exactly two decimal places. `printf` has its own little mini formatting language, you can read all about in the docs for [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html). That's printf but it doesn't print, it returns a string (the "s" is for "returns a string").

Then print out the list of `@unavailable` items.

```
say "Yes we have no ", join(", ", @unavailable), ".";
```

We need to join the elements of the list with commas to be formatted correctly. There's no need for a newline, `say` will add it for us.

Comment: hi @Schwern!! thank you so much for this. unfortunately when I run the code, this error comes up: "Argument "=>" isn't numeric in addition (+) at main.pl line 36. line 36 is where i put the code     '$total += $stash{item};'  what do you think is the issue??

Comment: does $stash{$item} access the costs/values of the items? or just the item name/keys?

Comment: @IwanttoLearnPerl To the error, somehow you put the string `=>` in as a value of `%stash`. You should be able to spot the mistake with a syntax highlighting editor like [Atom](https://atom.io/). As for `$stash{$item}`, that gets the value in `%stash` associated with `$item`. So `$stash{"tofu"}` is `0.30`.